# how to split a string in c# using regex.split method or any normal split method to get the output as below

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, regex-lookarounds

INPUT:

```
string s="([A-z]{1,})-([a-z]{1,})"
```

OUTPUT:
should result in an array containing:

```
([A-z]{1,})
([a-z]{1,})
```

Comment: **Warning:** `[A-z]` is an **error.**  It is *not* equivalent to `[A-Za-z]`.  **Never use `[A-z]` in a regex!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression that matches the start and end parentheses and everything between them:

```
string[] output =
  Regex.Matches(s, @"\([^\)]+\)+")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(x => x.Value)
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the string always at "-", then you can directly use string split no need of Regex because Regex is costly compare to string operations

```
 string values[]=s.split('-');
```